# can't connect to mysql database in servlet

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I keep getting this error when i'm trying to connect to my MySQL database:

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: JDBC Problem: 
root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
root cause

java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

here's some code:

```
Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection
                    ("jdbc:mysql://mysql11.000webhost.com/database_name","user_name","password");
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("INSERT into emailadresses('email') values ('"+email+"')");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EmailServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }catch(SQLException e){
            throw new ServletException("JDBC Problem: ", e);
        }
```

edit: I have the mysql-connector-java jar file in my libraries

EDIT: FOUND THE PROBLEM
I was looking for the answer on the site where I host my database and found this:

```
JDBC/ODBC is not supported here
```

that s*cks...

Comment: Are you able to connect manually from the same machine the jvm is running on?

Comment: One of the problems can be because you didn't specify the port. It should look like `jdbc:mysql://mysql11.000webhost.com:3306/database_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Signals that an error occurred while attempting to connect a socket to a remote address and port. Typically, the connection was refused remotely (e.g., no process is listening on the remote address/port)". - [From Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ConnectException.html)

Take a look into your connection string, be sure that the database, username and the password are correctly typed.

Another cause may be that your database server is not up.

Comment: I think the problem lies within my connection string; i really hate those things... can't seem to find the problem with it

Comment: Try to stop your firewall services, it may be blocking your connection.

Comment: i did block my firewalls, but it still gave me the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Yes its not a classpath problem, its a networking problem. For some reason no network connection can be established to the given host from your client machine. So yeah, could be lots of things.

- server is actually not running!
- host/IP wrong
- firewall (your side)
- firewall (other side)
- whatever else networking problem there might be

Comment: Don't forget `mysqld` listening on `127.0.0.1` rather than wan ip. That one catches lots of people out.

Comment: well, the server is running, and i can enter the database through phpmyadmin

Comment: typically `phpmyadmin` runs remotely, on the server alongside the `mysqld`, so no remote mysql connection is made.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a networking problem. Note that your tcp connection is **NOT** refused, instead it incurs in a timeout error. In my experience that behaviour could be caused by a TCP handshaking not correctly finalized (eg. a firewall dropping SYN packets).

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting that database from any database client(like sqlyog) from machine you are running your application. If connection fails from client also, then surely it's a network issue.